# JavaScript library for showing on mobile website banner to mobile app

Tags: javascript, mobile

One of website I am maintaining has mobile version and applications for Windows Phone, iOS and android. Is there any ready solution which will detect my mobile browser and show appropriate banner for application in Windows Phone, iOS or Android?

I am trying to find something useful but with no luck.

Example in Ios : [Banner - link 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Comment: by banner you mean the banner like in `safari` browser in `iOS`?

Comment: @Kyojimaru yes, something like in link I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by creating your own `function` to create the `banner` by checking the `User Agent`, though it will take some time to `style` it.

other ready solution is using `jQuery` plugin [smartbanner](http://jasny.github.io/jquery.smartbanner/), though the `UI` is a little bit different from the `safari browser` in `iOS`. It can't detect whether your user already installed your apps or not, so the button will always says either `Install` or other string that you type

Comment: I added this link as an example, so UI is not so important. The mechanism is. Thanks for help, I will check this one.

Comment: I used this one. Thanks for help!